# Processing : fill(int) VS fill(color) in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, colors, processing

So I discovered that the `color` datatype is, in fact, an int, read a bit about bit-shifting, in aim of making myself a class to handle this.

So here's the basic code (without getters/setters and with everything `public` for better understanding) :

```
public class Color{
  public int value; //the 'color' datatype as an int
  public int red, green, blue, alpha; //the components in RGB + Alpha

  public Color(Color c){
    this.value = c.value();
    alpha = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    red =   (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    green = (value >> 8)  & 0xFF;
    blue =  (value)       & 0xFF;
  }

  public Color(int red, int green, int blue, int alpha){
    this.red = checkValue(red);
    this.green = checkValue(green);
    this.blue = checkValue(blue);
    this.alpha = checkValue(alpha);
    value = (alpha << 24) & 0xFF
          | (red   << 16) & 0xFF
          | (green << 8) & 0xFF
          | (blue) & 0xFF;
  }

  //...
}
```

This seems to work fine, but :

```
Color c = new Color(255, 125, 645, 0);
fill(c.value); //shade of grey ?!
```

apparently calls fill(int grey), so I can only draw shades of grey this way, however

```
fill(c.red, c.green, c.blue, c.alpha); //the color I wanted
```

works exactly as intended.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or should I always use `fill(c.red, c.green, c.blue, c.alpha);` ?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve], including the definition of the `checkValue()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `color` datatype is pretty specific to the Processing editor. If you're using netbeans, I'm not sure you can use it anymore.

From [the Processing eclipse tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/):

> Another important note. The Processing "color" primitive does not
>   exist in Java. In fact, in Processing a "color" is really just an
>   integer (32 bits with red, green, blue, and alpha components).
>   Processing translates "color" to "int", but Eclipse won't do that for
>   you. So instead of saying:
>
> ```
> color pink = color(255,200,200);
> ```
>
> you should say:
>
> ```
> int pink = color(255,200,200);
> ```

Another clue would be to look at [Processing's source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PGraphics.java#L6668). That links to the `fill()` function, which uses the `colorCalc()` function to calculate the color based on an `int` value. You can trace through that to figure out exactly what's going on.

Using that you might be able to figure out a way to make a single `int` value work, but Processing storing colors as a single `int` value is part of the magic that you usually don't have to play with. If I were you I would just stick to keeping them separated as RGB values.

Comment: Using your link, I found the [colorCalc()](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PGraphics.java#L7522) method, but reading the javadoc it appears to me that it should recognize wether it's a grey-scale number or an ARGB value, right ? So I really don't understand why it doesn't work. Well, separating values work perfectly fine, but it's a bit verbose so I would've liked to make it work.

Comment: @CLOVISArtificialIntelligence If you want to keep investigating, the source for the `colorCalc()` function is the key. For example, this line of code is apparently evaluating to true: `if (((rgb & 0xff000000) == 0) && (rgb <= colorModeX)) {` Is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: ...Uh I really need to learn how bit-shifting works in details ... no matter how much I look at it, `rgb & 0xff000000` is a boolean so it should be a compiler error ... or I missed an entire part of `&` :/

Comment: I just created a new class method, `public void fill(PGraphics g){ g.fill(this.red, this.green, this.blue, this.alpha); }` until I understand what's actually going on :/

Comment: @CLOVISArtificialIntelligence A single ampersand `&` used with `int` values is **not** a boolean. It's a **bit-wise and** operator, which creates a new binary value by keeping `1`s wherever both arguments have `1`. So `& 0xff000000` clears out all of the `1`s` except the first 8, since `ff` is `1111 1111` in binary.